# What forces act on an element taken in a body which is subjected to no external forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, molecular-dynamics

Consider a block (rigid) which is lying on a table. If we take a differential element in the block and try to draw its Free-body diagram, will there be any forces other than gravitational force acting on the element?

[image]

---

I've had this conception in my mind since childhood that if I ever take out a chunk of any object there will be forces acting on that chunk because of the neighbouring molecules of the chunk and these forces will be such that the neighboring molecules are attracting this chunk. But I dont  truly understand why will these forces act? why are they attractive when felt by the chunk? and in the first place I don't know if this conception is right.

I wasn't able to find anything of the sort in the elementary physics textbooks that I had, so I am here to seek help.

Answer (score 1):

At a molecular level there are attractive forces between the molecules of any solid  - this is what stops the molecules on the surface of the object just drifting away, and so lets the object retain its shape. At a macroscopic level there will be internal pressure forces acting on each face of the element, and maybe shear forces as well. For example, the element must support the weight of the solid column above it, and it will in turn press down on the solid column below it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If we talk about an atom of a solid, why is it that we say that this atom experiences attraction from other nearby atoms, even though the e-e and p-p in them will repel?

Comment: @HarshitRajput [Dispersion forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force).

Answer (score 1):

There will be a number of forces acting on the atom/molecule. As @Chemomechanics said, dispersion forces will be acting on that scale. Also, depending on the kind of substance we’re talking about, we can have dipole-dipole forces, induced-dipole forces, hydrogen bonding, and such. The above mentioned forces are attractive in nature.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple geometry of the block, any small volume element has a downward force due to the mass above it. This force acts on the top surface of the volume.

On the other hand, its bottom surface must hold not only that mass, but also the weight of the chunk itself. If everything is at rest, the sum of that forces is zero:
$$F_b - (F_u + w) = 0$$
Force is stress multiplied by area, and weight is density multiplied by volume and gravity acceleration. Taking $h$ as the height of the bottom of the volume:
$$\sigma_h\Delta A - \sigma_{h+\Delta h}\Delta A = \rho g\Delta A \Delta h$$
Dividing by the volume $\Delta A \Delta h$:
$$\frac{\Delta \sigma}{\Delta h} = \rho g$$

While we know that at very small scale the solid is discontinuous, composed by molecules and/or atoms, it is possible to use calculus by let $\Delta h$ be small enough to be treated as an infinitesimal, but great enough to have  an homogeneous feature. With that assumption, the stress can be modeled as a differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial h} = \rho g$$
Solving the equation, and setting force equals zero on the top surface of the body:
$$\sigma = \rho g(h - H)$$ where H is the height of the block. The compressive stress grows linearly from top to bottom.